# Worklight change message title

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.1

Is there a way to change the "Application Disabled" title when disabling app the in the admin console.

We are upgrading some servers that our app uses for information over the weekend and was wondering if there was a way to change the title to "Application Unavailable"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change this string.

The string is located in the application resources, not in the console. Worklight Console only provides the message that will be displayed in the application.

To find it, look in iphone\native\Resources\Localizations.bundle\en.lang in Worklight Studio (or when in Xcode).
The way to handle (localization) strings in iOS is via the localization bundles, either by (native) code or/and localization files.

BTW, "Application Unavailable" would be a false statement; the *application* is available; it is the *connectivity to Worklight Server* that will not be available. I guess even the default string is an odd choice in this case...

When the application is disabled you only get an 'OK' button. Once the user taps the OK button, s/he can still access the app, but any action that triggers a request to the server will cause the dialog to display again.

This, of course, can be avoided [by customizing the behavior of Remote Disable](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_create_a_customized_remote_disable_behavior?lang=en).

---

To preserve your strings changes outside of the native folder, use the nativeResources folder by recreating the folder structure to file, and save it there: nativeResources\Resources\Localizations.bundle\en.lang

During application build, it should be auto-copied over to the native folder.

Comment: Thanks, the onErrorRemoteDisableDenial is what i was looking for. Though wont help me this time, will implement it for next time.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest fix pack of Worklight 6.1, the message title has been changed to "Access to Server is Disabled", and you can also make some choices about what the user of the mobile app can do in this case (let them continue to use the application without connectivity to the Worklight Server, or force the application to exit).  You can find information about this in the documentation, here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/t_denying_access_to_older_app_versions.html

We do not, however, provide a way for the developer or administrator to change the actual title of the message box.